# Does Azure functions have any pre-installed npm packages? If so, how may I check them?

Tags: node.js, azure, npm, azure-functions

I'm trying to develop an Azure function locally using WebStorm/PHPStorm, was wondering if Azure functions have any pre-installed/built-in npm packages ready in the cloud, since deploying my final product becomes a process if I want to include all of them. If so, how may I check which ones are available?

Comment: If you mean packages about binding extensions, the registration
in Functions 3.x/2.x in portal is automatically. If you mean runtime stack, it is also automatically prepared after you created your function.

Comment: @DorisLv Thank you for your comment, my issue is that I am developing my function locally with all the necessary dependencies, however, I want to know if Azure provides any npm packages on server side.

Comment: You can refer to this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node#dependency-management

Comment: We do not have access to all folders, so we can only see a collection of pre-installed packages. It is in %ProgramFiles(x86)%\SiteExtensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go to `https://yourfunctionappname.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole` to check.

If you run `npm list -g --depth=0`, you will get nothing.

We do not have access rights to all folders, so we cannot view the specific software packages used after configuration on the system drive, but can only see a series of packages that came with the creation of the function app.

Azure Function is based on web app sand box, so you can find pre-installed package in this folder: `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\SiteExtensions`(There will be many version.)

https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Site-Extensions#pre-installed-site-extensions-package

Comment: Thanks for the help Bowman, what you are saying is Azure provides necessary packages needed to run the function AFTER the creation/deployment of my function, which essentially means that it does not contain pre-installed packages?

Comment: @2Xchampion If you check the nodejs-worker of azure function on github, you will find that there is no special mention of pre-installed packages at all. (Correspondingly, python-worker specifically mentioned pre-installed packages) So you can basically think that it does not have pre-installed npm packages. We have no way to check because there is no access rights.

Comment: thanks again for the prompt reply, I understand now, I did go into function templates and was not able to find much about node.js packages, now that you mentioned it, it all makes sense now. Many thanks!